# XPATH getting text inside balise that contains balise which contains text

Tags: html, xpath

My html :

```
<div class="my class">
    <p style="padding:3px;">
        <b> Série :</b>
        my text I need to got with my xpath expression
    </p>
```

For now I have : `'//div[@class="my class"]/p[b[contains(., \'Série :\')]]'` But the last part with the contains isn't working. I really need to say that i want the text from a balise p that contains balise b which contains text "Serie" because there is an other structures like that with the only difference being the text in that famous balise.

Comment: Your `b` tag is not correct. Do you mean `<b> Série :</b>`? Also your XPath should have extra closing square bracket

Comment: Yeah I forgot the ">" and also one "]" my bad it's edited.

Comment: What is the point of escaping single quotes if you can just use double quotes `contains(., "Série :")`?

Comment: It's the same. I choose to escape but yesi  could have used double quotes

Comment: XPath seem to be correct. Can you elaborate a little about `the last part with the contains isn't working`? How do you use your XPath? Share your current code and current output

Comment: I mean if I stop with '/p[b]' it will took every text that have a balise b inside a balise p. But any time I try to specify that i need the one with the balise b containing a word, my xpath won't match anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get only the text after the `<b>` tag, you can use an index on the `text()` node

```
//div[@class='my class']/p[contains(b, 'Série :')]/text()[2]
```

An alternative to this approach is using the `following::` axis

```
//div[@class='my class']/p[contains(b, 'Série :')]/b/following::text()
```

Output in both cases is:

```
   my text I need to got with my xpath expression
```

Comment: For information, the text I need to get back isn't in my balise b (she is closed) but in my balise p. I tried both ways and it still not working. result is none like my xpath won't find anything matching

Comment: Thanks to your proposal and with some work on it, I managed to make it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: xpath that worked : '//div[@class="pvo-pave-contenu"]/p[contains(b, "Série :")]/text()'

Comment: That's interesting. Maybe your real file differs in some aspect from the sample, or your XPath program handles `text()` nodes differently. However, good that you found a solution that works.